# How can I implement a 1s delay before my progress/cancel dialog is shown?

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading, async-await, c#-5.0

I'm trying to construct a progress/cancel form for use within my WinForms application that runs any await-able "operation", while providing the user with some progress information and an opportunity to cancel the operation.

Because the form is shown using `ShowDialog()`, it's a modal form which nicely disables the form underneath - so I don't need to mess around with disabling all the controls on that other form.

They way I've implemented it, which I fully expect you to rip to shreds :-), is to await the result of the operation during the `Form.Load` event handler, and then close the form once the operation is either completed (whether that be because it ran to completion, was cancelled, or raise an exception).

```
public partial class ProgressForm<T> : Form
{
    private CancellationTokenSource _cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    private Progress<string> _progress = new Progress<string>();
    private Func<IProgress<string>, CancellationToken, Task<T>> _operation = null;
    private Exception _exception = null;
    private T _result = default(T);


    public static T Execute(Func<IProgress<string>, CancellationToken, Task<T>> operation)
    {
        using (var progressForm = new ProgressForm<T>())
        {
            progressForm._operation = operation;

            progressForm.ShowDialog();

            if (progressForm._exception != null)
                throw progressForm._exception;
            else
                return progressForm._result;
        }
    }


    public ProgressForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this._progress.ProgressChanged += ((o, i) => this.ProgressLabel.Text = i.ToString());
    }

    private async void ProgressForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            this._result = await this._operation(this._progress, this._cancellationTokenSource.Token);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) // Includes OperationCancelledException
        {
            this._exception = ex;
        }

        this.Close();
    }

    private void CancelXButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this._cancellationTokenSource != null)
            this._cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
    }
}
```

This is called like this:

```
int numberOfWidgets = ProgressForm<int>.Execute(CountWidgets);
```

...where `CountWidgets()` is an await-able thing (in this case a function returning `Task<int>`, with appropriate IProgress and `CancellationToken` parameters).

So far it works pretty well, but there's one "feature" that I'd like to add. Ideally, I'd like the form to remain invisible for (say) one second, so that if the operation completes really quickly there's no "flicker" as the form is shown and then immediately hidden again.

So, my question is how to introduce the 1s delay before the form is shown. Obviously, I still want to start the operation immediately, and yet as soon as I "await" the result of the operation, I'm no longer in control (so to speak) because control will be returned to the caller of the `Form.Load` event handler - which will continue the work of showing the form.

I suspect that essentially I really need a second thread, and that I need the operation to execute on that thread while I block the main UI thread. (I know that blocking the UI thread is frowned upon, but in this case I think it's actually what I need).

There are so many different ways of creating threads, etc. that I'm not sure how to do this in the new "async/await" world...

Comment: It's not really clear how it's all working - we don't have enough context of where the code you've shown fits into the rest of your code.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Full code for the form added.

Comment: So, you want 1 s delay, and what if the whole process takes, for example, 1.5 seconds? The same problem remains. You need to think about something else.

Comment: I would add this delay after the process finished, before closing the dialog, if execution time was too short.

Comment: @AlexFarber: I agree that - no matter where you set the time limit - there's always a chance that the operation will complete just after the time limit. However, on the basis that I expect most operations to be sub-second, I think I can cut the flicker down to an acceptable level by using a 1s delay before showing the dialog. Note that I want the "normal" behaviour to be the the user never sees the dialog at all, and so adding the delay at the end so that the dialog shows every time - and for longer - is not an attractive proposition.

Comment: @Gary: You'll need to either block the UI for a second or disable it for a second. Are you sure this is what you want to do?

Comment: We did this by using a singleton. So a calling display the progress form set's a timer up. Stoped dislaying the progress kills the form or the timer.

Comment: @StephenCleary: Yes, I'm happy for the UI to block for a second. In fact, that's the desired behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll have to separate out your "task runner" from your "dialog" in order to do this. First, a dialog that responds to progress and can issue a cancel:

```
public partial class ProgressForm : Form
{
  private readonly CancellationTokenSource _cancellationTokenSource;

  public ProgressForm(CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource, IProgress<string> progress)
  {
    InitializeComponent();

    _cancellationTokenSource = cancellationTokenSource;
    progress.ProgressChanged += ((o, i) => this.ProgressLabel.Text = i.ToString());
  }

  public static void ShowDialog(CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource, IProgress<string> progress)
  {
    using (var progressForm = new ProgressForm(cancellationTokenSource, progress))
    {
        progressForm.ShowDialog();
    }
  }

  private void CancelXButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    if (this._cancellationTokenSource != null)
      this._cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
  }
}
```

Next, the actual "task runner":

```
public static class FriendlyTaskRunner
{
  public static async Task<T> Execute<T>(Func<CancellationToken, IProgress<string>, Task<T>> operation)
  {
    var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var progress = new Progress<string>();
    var timeout = Task.Delay(1000);
    var operationTask = operation(cancellationTokenSource.Token, progress);

    // Synchronously block for either the operation to complete or a timeout;
    //  if the operation completes first, just return the result.
    var completedTask = Task.WhenAny(timeout, operationTask).Result;
    if (completedTask == operationTask)
      return await operationTask;

    // Kick off a progress form and have it close when the task completes.
    using (var progressForm = new ProgressForm(cancellationTokenSource, progress))
    {
      operationTask.ContinueWith(_ => { progressForm.Close(); });
      progressForm.ShowDialog();
    }

    return await operationTask;
  }
}
```

Please note that [synchronously blocking the UI thread may cause deadlocks](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) - in this case, if `operation` attempts to sync back to the UI thread, it would be blocked until after the timeout - so it's not a true "deadlock" but quite inefficient.

Comment: Thanks, that's awesome :-)  It does suffer from the same problem as Hans Passant's answer (now deleted) where, because ShowDialog is not being called immediately, we don't get the side-benefit of disabling the underlying form for the duration of the operation. However, there are other ways to deal with that.

Comment: One question: if an exception is raised by the operationTask during the await Task.WhenAny() call, what kind of exception will be returned to the caller of that Execute() method? Do I need to start worrying about AggregateExceptions?

Comment: @Gary: I modified the code so that it (synchronously) blocks for up to a second and then will call ShowDialog without yielding. Personally, I would prefer disabling the calling form, displaying the dialog with a regular Show, and then registering a continuation to close the form. But this was easier.

Comment: @Gary: The code handles exceptions cleanly. Only once is `Task.Result` used, and that's used on the `Task.WhenAny` return value, which [always completes in a successful state](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194796.aspx). BTW, your original code would lose the stack trace if `operation` threw an exception.

Comment: For anyone trying to use this code, you'll probably notice a bug: the `ContinueWith` part towards the end will execute the `progressForm.Close()` call on a random ThreadPool thread, and will then raise an `InvalidOperationException` because it can only execute on the UI thread. I was able to fix this by using `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()` as the second parameter to `ContinueWith`.

Comment: Also, FYI, I was able to refactor the code such that the progress dialog is just an ordinary dialog, with none of the `CancellationToken` or `Progress` stuff in it. To signal cancellation, the cancel button just needs to set `DialogResult.Cancel`, and then you just need to check the result of  the `ShowDialog` call. If it's `DialogResult.Cancel`, then call `Cancel` on the `CancellationToken`.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend keeping parts of what you have if you want to delay display of the form.  I would invoke the operation independently then create a `Timer` whose `Tick` event handler checks to see if the task is complete and if it is, does nothing.  Otherwise it should create the form, passing the `IProgress<T>` and `CancellationTokenSource`, and task into the form.  You can still await a task that has already be started.   For the task to be started, it will need the progress object and the cancellation token before the form is created--so that needs to be created independently...

Comment: Thanks. You're the Nth person to recommend that I don't show the form until after the delay period. You're (all) probably right. The reason I was attracted to showing (or rather, creating) the form immediately is that it had the side-benefit of disabling the form underneath for the duration of the operation, which is useful. However, as I've said elsewhere, there are other ways to achieve the same thing.

Comment: You can easily disable the "parent" form.  I would recommend disabling only a subset of controls (like the ones uses to spawn this operation).  But, you can simply use `Form.Enabled` to disable it and re-enable it in the `Tick` handler or in the child form if it gets shown.