# Why do I get a compiler warning when using ContinueWith?

Tags: c#, .net-4.5, compiler-warnings, async-await

I have this line of code:

```
t.ContinueWith(_ => form.Close(), 
                  TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

...about which the compiler has this to say:

> Warning   2   Because this call is not awaited, execution of the current method continues before the call is completed. Consider applying the 'await' operator to the result of the call.

Now, this wasn't code that I wrote, but I thought that it's simply adding a continuation to the end of an existing task. I didn't think it's actually *running* the task (or the continuation). So surely this process of merely modifying the task is a synchronous operation? Why would I have to `await` it?

Comment: Could you post the entire method?

Comment: Stephen, it's your code :-)  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/12513296/98422

Comment: Without the surrounding code, I'm not sure, but why not just await t and then form.Close?

Comment: The surrounding code is available in the link above (2 comments up). The task t is already in progress, and the point of that surrounding code is to display a progress dialog while t executes, so `await`-ing t would be inappropriate here.

Comment: That'll teach me to post code without compiling it! :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Why would I have to `await` it?

You don't have to `await` it, that's why it is a warning, not an error. But, if you're in an `async` method and you have a method that returns an awaitable object, most of the time, you shouldn't ignore it.

In normal synchronous code, you don't have to do anything special to wait until a method you called completes, each method call always blocks. But with asynchronous methods, you actually have to `await` them if you want to wait until they complete. Also, if the asynchronous operation fails and throws an exception, you won't know about it until you `await` the result of the method (or get the exception from the result some other way, such as calling `Wait()` if the awaitable is a `Task`).

So, if you ignore a returned awaitable value in an `async` method, it's likely that you have a bug in your code, which is what the warning is trying to avoid.

In your case, `ContinueWith()` returns a `Task`, which *can* be `await`ed, so the compiler assumes that you *should* `await` it. But in this case, you don't want to wait until the continuation completes and `Close()` most likely won't throw an exception. So, in this case, the warning is a false positive, it does not actually indicate a problem in the code.

Comment: Great answer, thanks. Is there anything I can do to stop the warning from appearing, and thus obscuring all the _actual_ problems? (I don't want to disable the warning in other cases, just here).

Comment: You could disable it just for this method if you add `#pragma warning disable 4014` before then method and `#pragma warning restore 4014` after it. Usually, I would recommend you to fix what the warning is complaining about, but in this case, there isn't really anything to fix, so disabling the warning just for this method makes sense, I think.

Comment: Another option is to assign the task to a variable. And then simply ignore the variable.

Comment: Thanks @svick. Wouldn't it be nice if that warning number was *in the frigging warning message*, so I didn't need to waste 10 minutes trying to track it down?